# How can I get the index of an object in an array with a property value that matches a specific criteria?

Tags: ios, swift

Maybe this question has already been answered before or the answer is so obvious but I've been searching for days and cannot find an answer to this problem. I would appreciate any help on this as I'm at my wits' end.

```
class marker {
    var latitude = Double()
    var longitude = Double()
    var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
}

let someCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(someLatitude, someLongitude)
```

Now let's say that I have an array named "markers" of 10 marker objects with all properties already initialized. How can I find the index of the marker item whose coordinate value matches the value of someCoordinate?

**EDIT**

While trying out the suggestion of [iosdk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4892417/oisdk) below, I found out that I was trying to compare the marker.coordinate property which is a CLLocationCoordinate2D. That did not work as I expected. Instead I tried this and it worked:

```
let markerIndex = indexOfMarker(markers) { $0.position.latitude == latitude && $0.position.longitude == longitude }
```

Comment: It would help to have a small sample of the structure you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct SomeStruct {
  let a, b: Int
}

let one = SomeStruct(a: 1, b: 1)
let two = SomeStruct(a: 2, b: 2)
let three = SomeStruct(a: 3, b: 3)

let ar = [one, two, three]

let ans = ar.indexOf { $0.a == 2 } // 1?
```

Or, on Swift 1, the indexOf function can be:

```
func indexOfOld<S : SequenceType>(seq: S, predicate: S.Generator.Element -> Bool) -> Int? {

  for (index, value) in enumerate(seq) {
    if predicate(value) {
      return index
    }
  }
  return nil
}
```

And you'd replace the last line above with:

```
let ans = indexOfOld(ar) { $0.a == 2 } // 1?
```

Comment: Which is probably why Swift 1 syntax is a learning nightmare/remembering: `SequenceType`, `S.Generator.Element`.

Comment: I'm on Swift 1. I tried your suggestion and it works very well. I thought that getting an index would be very simple to do in Swift. I saw the indexOf in several places but it doesn't seem to work for this version of Swift. Thanks for your help.